# Render Menu Bar from a single class and highlight the menu dynamically in Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2, render

I have my top menu bar in my Yii2 project in a separate. I render them in my index file and use them.

**js file to use active class dynamically.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location;
    // Will only work if string in href matches with location
    $('ul.navbark a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    // Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
    $('ul.navbark a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

It works great. It assigns active class accurately but the issue is whenn I use search in the same page. the URL changes which is causing an issue. When I submit a search form the active class is removed. How can I fix this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you give an example how your URL looks like when it works and when it breaks? It is most likely you will need to do some splitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution for my question:

As of now I haven't used yii2 Navbar instead have used html. When I use yii2 Navbar I don't have to call any javascript.

**This my view page for the menu bar: views/topmenu/chemicalinventory.php**

```
<?php echo yii\bootstrap\Nav::widget([
    'items' => [
        ['label' => Yii::t('app','Inventory'),'url' => ['/product/index']],
        ['label' => Yii::t('app','Requests'),'url' => ['/product-requests/index']],
        ['label' => Yii::t('app','Deleted'),'url' => ['/productlines-deleted/index']],
    ],
    'options' => ['class' =>'nav nav-tabs nav-tab nav-text navbark'],    
]);
?>
```

Now I can render this in any of my view page.

```
 <?php echo \Yii::$app->view->renderFile('@app/views/topmenu/chemicalinventory.php'); ?>
```

**The css for my top menu is**

```
.nav-tab-pills { border-bottom: 3px solid #DDD; }
    .nav-tab-pills > li.active > a, .nav-tab > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tab-pills > li.active > a:hover { border-width: 0;background-color:#F7F7F7; }
    .nav-tab-pills > li > a { border: none; color: gray; }
        .nav-tab-pills > li.active > a, .nav-tab-pills > li > a:hover { border: none; color: #1ABB9C !important; background: transparent; }
        .nav-tab-pills > li > a::after { content: ""; background: #2A3F54; height: 3px; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0px; bottom: -1px; transition: all 250ms ease 0s ; transform: scale(0); }
    .nav-tab-pills > li.active > a::after, .nav-tab-pills > li:hover > a::after {transform: scale(1); }
.tab-nav-pills > li > a::after { background: #21527d none repeat scroll 0% 0%;}
.tab-pane { padding: 15px 0; }
.tab-content{padding:20px}
.nav-text{font-weight: bold}
.nav-text{font-size: 15px;}
```

This will give an output something like the image below:

[image: Click Here]